# Sinon stub function parameter

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, sinon, sinon-chai

I have an express app with a router I would like to test with Sinon. I'm not successful in mocking the `response` parameter that is passed into the request handler and would like some help.

```js
export const pingHandler = (request, response, next) => {
    response.status(200).send('Hello world');
}
```

This is my current test setup using Mocha, Sinon, Chai & sinon-chai. `fakeRes.status` was never called as expected.

```js
describe("pingHandler", () => {
    it("should return 200", async () => {
        const fakeResponse = {
            status: sinon.fake(() => ({
                send: sinon.spy()
            }))
        };
        pingHandler({}, fakeResponse, {});
        expect(fakeResponse.status).to.have.been.called;
        // => expected fake to have been called at least once, but it was never called
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the unit test solution:

`index.ts`:

```js
export const pingHandler = (request, response, next) => {
  response.status(200).send('Hello world');
}
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import { pingHandler } from "./";
import sinon from "sinon";

describe("pingHandler", () => {
  it("should return 200", () => {
    const mRes = {
      status: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
      send: sinon.stub(),
    };

    pingHandler({}, mRes, {});
    sinon.assert.calledWith(mRes.status, 200);
    sinon.assert.calledWith(mRes.send, "Hello world");
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 pingHandler
    ✓ should return 200


  1 passing (8ms)

---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File           |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.spec.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts      |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
---------------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
```

Comment: Wow, brilliant answer! Thanks a lot!